# Как реализовать многопоточность в PyQt

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Я уже задавал вопрос по этому коду [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1338653/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-pyqt5?noredirect=1#comment2370584_1338653), там у меня зависала программа при исполнении главного алгоритма и мне посоветовали сделать многопоточный процесс.

Я попытался, но не могу понять как реализовать это. 
Как и где нужно создавать объект `Thread` и как правильно передать его в функцию, которая будет запускаться при нажатии на кнопку.

Цель у программы следующая: она берет по **`1`** фотографии из **`5`** различных папок и создает из них одно изображение. 
Все данные для цикла основного алгоритма (imageobr) представляются в виде переменных, которые получены путем обработки этих папок (количество изображений в папке, пустое изображение для перезаписи, пути для чтения, путь для сохранения), но программа не желает работать должным образом и зависает.

```py
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from threading import Thread
step = 0
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(816, 601)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 404, 231))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.folder_path_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.folder_path_label.setFont(font)
        self.folder_path_label.setObjectName("folder_path_label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.folder_path_label)
        self.btn_browse_path_folder = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.btn_browse_path_folder.setObjectName("btn_browse_path_folder")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_browse_path_folder)
        self.path1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.path1.setText("")
        self.path1.setObjectName("path1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.path1)
        self.save_path_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.save_path_label.setFont(font)
        self.save_path_label.setObjectName("save_path_label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.save_path_label)
        self.btn_browse_save_folder = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.btn_browse_save_folder.setObjectName("btn_browse_save_folder")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_browse_save_folder)
        self.path2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.path2.setText("")
        self.path2.setObjectName("path2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.path2)
        self.inf_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.inf_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 0, 211, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.inf_label.setFont(font)
        self.inf_label.setObjectName("inf_label")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 20, 251, 211))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.count_frames_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.count_frames_label.setFont(font)
        self.count_frames_label.setObjectName("count_frames_label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.count_frames_label)
        self.count_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.count_label.setFont(font)
        self.count_label.setText("")
        self.count_label.setObjectName("count_label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.count_label)
        self.size_img_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.size_img_label.setFont(font)
        self.size_img_label.setObjectName("size_img_label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.size_img_label)
        self.size_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.size_label.setFont(font)
        self.size_label.setText("")
        self.size_label.setObjectName("size_label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.size_label)
        self.finish_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.finish_label.setFont(font)
        self.finish_label.setText("")
        self.finish_label.setObjectName("finish_label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.finish_label)
        self.btn_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(680, 20, 131, 141))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.btn_start.setFont(font)
        self.btn_start.setObjectName("btn_start")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 230, 791, 291))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_3.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_3")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.image_label.setText("")
        self.image_label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.image_label.setObjectName("image_label")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 530, 321, 42))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.status_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.status_label.setFont(font)
        self.status_label.setObjectName("status_label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.status_label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.steps_status_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.steps_status_label.setFont(font)
        self.steps_status_label.setText("")
        self.steps_status_label.setObjectName("steps_status_label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.steps_status_label, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 530, 441, 41))
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_2")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.gridLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.progress_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.progress_label.setFont(font)
        self.progress_label.setObjectName("progress_label")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.progress_label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.progressBar, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.btn_browse_path_folder.clicked.connect(
            self.browsefiles1)  # если нажал на кнопку для указания пути к папкам 12345
        self.btn_browse_save_folder.clicked.connect(self.browsefiles2)  # если нажал на кнопку для указания пути сохранения
        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.start)

    # -------------------------#
    def browsefiles1(self):
        global folder_path
        global num_files
        global column
        global row
        folder_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Выбрать папку", ".")
        self.path1.setText(folder_path)
        num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(folder_path + '/1')
                         if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path + '/1', f))])
        self.count_label.setText(str(num_files))
        img_test = Image.open(folder_path + '/empty.tif')
        (column, row) = img_test.size
        self.size_label.setText(str(column) + 'px' + ' X ' + str(row) + 'px')

    # -------------------------#
    def browsefiles2(self):
        global save_path
        save_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Выбрать папку", ".")
        self.path2.setText(save_path)

    # методы для открытия обзорщика файлов и выбора папки
    # -------------------------#
    global th2
    global th1
    def imageobr(self):
        global string_step
        global step
        global img0

        count = 2  # количество столбиков, которое нужно взять
        for step in range(0, num_files + 1):
            if step < 10:
                string_step = '000' + str(step)
            if (step >= 10) and (step < 100):
                string_step = '00' + str(step)
            if (step >= 100):
                string_step = '0' + str(step)
            img0 = np.array(Image.open(folder_path + '/empty.tif').convert('RGB'))
            img1 = np.array(Image.open(folder_path + '/1/folder1w' + string_step + '.tif').convert('RGB'))
            img2 = np.array(Image.open(folder_path + '/2/folder2w' + string_step + '.tif').convert('RGB'))
            img3 = np.array(Image.open(folder_path + '/3/folder3w' + string_step + '.tif').convert('RGB'))
            img4 = np.array(Image.open(folder_path + '/4/folder4w' + string_step + '.tif').convert('RGB'))
            img5 = np.array(Image.open(folder_path + '/5/folder5w' + string_step + '.tif').convert('RGB'))
            # с какой строчки начинаем (0,2,4,6,8)
            space = 8  # 8 промежуток между столбцами
            first_column = 0
            for i in range(first_column, column, space + 2):
                for j in range(0, row):
                    img0[j][i + count - 1] = img1[j][i + count - 1]
                    img0[j][i] = img1[j][i]
            first_column = 2
            for i in range(first_column, column, space + 2):
                for j in range(0, row):
                    img0[j][i + count - 1] = img2[j][i + count - 1]
                    img0[j][i] = img2[j][i]
            first_column = 4
            for i in range(first_column, column, space + 2):
                for j in range(0, row):
                    img0[j][i + count - 1] = img3[j][i + count - 1]
                    img0[j][i] = img3[j][i]
            first_column = 6
            for i in range(first_column, column, space + 2):
                for j in range(0, row):
                    img0[j][i + count - 1] = img4[j][i + count - 1]
                    img0[j][i] = img4[j][i]
            first_column = 8
            for i in range(first_column, column, space + 2):
                for j in range(0, row):
                    img0[j][i + count - 1] = img5[j][i + count - 1]
                    img0[j][i] = img5[j][i]
            img = Image.fromarray(img0, 'RGB')
            img.save(save_path + '/frame' + str(step) + '.jpg')
    # -------------------------#
    def uilabels(self):
        self.steps_status_label.setText(str(step)+' из '+str(num_files))
    th1 = Thread(target=imageobr, args=None)
    th2 = Thread(target=uilabels, args=None)
    def start(self):
        th1.start()
        th2.start()
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.folder_path_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите путь к папкам с изображениями"))
        self.btn_browse_path_folder.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обзор"))
        self.save_path_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите путь для сохранения изображений"))
        self.btn_browse_save_folder.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обзор"))
        self.inf_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Информация:"))
        self.count_frames_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Количество кадров:"))
        self.size_img_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Размер изображений:"))
        self.btn_start.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать обработку"))
        self.status_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Статус:"))
        self.progress_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Прогресс:"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Я пробовал запустить ваш пример из предыдущего вопроса, но не получилось. То папки какой-то не, то файла нет. Если вам действительно нужна помощь, детально опишите какие папки надо создать. Какие изображения (опубликуйте их) надо положить в каждую папку. И опишите порядок действий, которые надо выполнить, чтобы получить ваше зависание. И как-то изобразите результат того, что вы хотите получить на выходе.

Comment: здравствуйте, спасибо. извиняюсь, я прикрепил код, в котором при нажатии на кнопки по умолчанию открывались мои директории, я исправил код, теперь открывается папка проекта (если открывали в PyCharm, как это делал я) https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MHaPDX2bl2a7lAOfL5rUtFSJiBwM7bLH?usp=sharing это ссылка на гугл диск где лежит пример папок и изображений в них, путь для сохранения может быть любым. на счет ошибки, первоначальная версия кода (представлена в ссылке в посте) работала следующим образом: изображения обрабатывались, но весь интерфейс дико зависал и ничего в интерфейс не выводи

Comment: лось, но теперь, когда я попытался использовать многопоточность, алгоритм просто не запускается, не знаю как правильно ее реализовать, чтобы и работал алгоритм обработки, и данные из этого цикла могли выводиться в интерфейсе, все переменные сделал глобальными, но это не помогло

Answer (score 1):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, **НИКОГДА !!!**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Да, дополнительный поток вам нужен, т.к. расчеты у вас тяжелые. Если что-то не понятно - спросите.

Да и глобальные переменные - это ЗЛО.

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(816, 650)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 404, 231))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.folder_path_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.folder_path_label.setFont(font)
        self.folder_path_label.setObjectName("folder_path_label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.folder_path_label)
        self.btn_browse_path_folder = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.btn_browse_path_folder.setObjectName("btn_browse_path_folder")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_browse_path_folder)
        self.path1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.path1.setText("")
        self.path1.setObjectName("path1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.path1)
        self.save_path_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.save_path_label.setFont(font)
        self.save_path_label.setObjectName("save_path_label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.save_path_label)
        self.btn_browse_save_folder = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.btn_browse_save_folder.setObjectName("btn_browse_save_folder")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_browse_save_folder)
        self.path2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.path2.setText("")
        self.path2.setObjectName("path2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.path2)
        self.inf_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.inf_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 0, 211, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.inf_label.setFont(font)
        self.inf_label.setObjectName("inf_label")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 20, 251, 211))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.count_frames_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.count_frames_label.setFont(font)
        self.count_frames_label.setObjectName("count_frames_label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.count_frames_label)
        self.count_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.count_label.setFont(font)
        self.count_label.setText("")
        self.count_label.setObjectName("count_label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.count_label)
        self.size_img_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.size_img_label.setFont(font)
        self.size_img_label.setObjectName("size_img_label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.size_img_label)
        self.size_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.size_label.setFont(font)
        self.size_label.setText("")
        self.size_label.setObjectName("size_label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.size_label)
        self.finish_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.finish_label.setFont(font)
        self.finish_label.setText("")
        self.finish_label.setObjectName("finish_label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.finish_label)
        self.btn_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(680, 20, 131, 141))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.btn_start.setFont(font)
        self.btn_start.setObjectName("btn_start")
# !!!
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
#       self.verticalLayoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 230, 791, 291))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 230, 791, 340))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_3.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_3")
        
# !!!        
#        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_3)
#                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")

        '''
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.image_label.setText("")
        self.image_label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.image_label.setObjectName("image_label")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.image_label)
        '''
        
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
#        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 530, 321, 42))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 600, 321, 42))
        
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.status_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.status_label.setFont(font)
        self.status_label.setObjectName("status_label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.status_label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.steps_status_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.steps_status_label.setFont(font)
        self.steps_status_label.setText("")
        self.steps_status_label.setObjectName("steps_status_label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.steps_status_label, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
#                                                            vvv        
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 600, 441, 41))
        
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_2")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.gridLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.progress_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.progress_label.setFont(font)
        self.progress_label.setObjectName("progress_label")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.progress_label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.progressBar, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.folder_path_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите путь к папкам с изображениями"))
        self.btn_browse_path_folder.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обзор"))
        self.save_path_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите путь для сохранения изображений"))
        self.btn_browse_save_folder.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обзор"))
        self.inf_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Информация:"))
        self.count_frames_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Количество кадров:"))
        self.size_img_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Размер изображений:"))
        self.btn_start.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать обработку"))
        self.status_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Статус:"))
        self.progress_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Прогресс:"))


class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    stepSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, str)
    
    def __init__(self, num_files, folder_path, save_path, row, column, parent=None):
        super(Thread, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.num_files = num_files
        self.folder_path = folder_path
        self.save_path = save_path
        self.row = row
        self.column = column

    def run(self):
        count = 2  # количество столбиков, которое нужно взять
        for step in range(0, self.num_files):                          # ??? + 1):
            print(f'step = {step}')                                    #
            
            if step < 10:
                string_step = '000' + str(step)
            if (step >= 10) and (step < 100):
                string_step = '00' + str(step)
            if (step >= 100):
                string_step = '0' + str(step)
                
            img0 = np.array(Image.open(self.folder_path + '/empty.tif').convert('RGB'))
            img1 = np.array(Image.open(
                self.folder_path + '/1/folder1w' + string_step + '.tif').convert('RGB'))
            img2 = np.array(Image.open(self.folder_path + '/2/folder2w' + string_step + '.tif').convert('RGB'))
            img3 = np.array(Image.open(self.folder_path + '/3/folder3w' + string_step + '.tif').convert('RGB'))
            img4 = np.array(Image.open(self.folder_path + '/4/folder4w' + string_step + '.tif').convert('RGB'))
            img5 = np.array(Image.open(self.folder_path + '/5/folder5w' + string_step + '.tif').convert('RGB'))

            # с какой строчки начинаем (0,2,4,6,8)
            space = 8                         # 8 промежуток между столбцами
            first_column = 0
            for i in range(first_column, self.column, space + 2):
                for j in range(0, self.row):
                    img0[j][i + count - 1] = img1[j][i + count - 1]
                    img0[j][i] = img1[j][i]
            first_column = 2
            for i in range(first_column, self.column, space + 2):
                for j in range(0, self.row):
                    img0[j][i + count - 1] = img2[j][i + count - 1]
                    img0[j][i] = img2[j][i]
            first_column = 4
            for i in range(first_column, self.column, space + 2):
                for j in range(0, self.row):
                    img0[j][i + count - 1] = img3[j][i + count - 1]
                    img0[j][i] = img3[j][i]
            first_column = 6
            for i in range(first_column, self.column, space + 2):
                for j in range(0, self.row):
                    img0[j][i + count - 1] = img4[j][i + count - 1]
                    img0[j][i] = img4[j][i]
            first_column = 8
            for i in range(first_column, self.column, space + 2):
                for j in range(0, self.row):
                    img0[j][i + count - 1] = img5[j][i + count - 1]
                    img0[j][i] = img5[j][i]
            img = Image.fromarray(img0, 'RGB')
            
            path = self.save_path + '/frame' + str(step) + '.jpg'
            img.save(path)

            self.stepSignal.emit(step, path)
            self.msleep(100)
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        # если нажал на кнопку для указания пути к папкам 12345
        self.btn_browse_path_folder.clicked.connect(
            self.browsefiles1)  
        # если нажал на кнопку для указания пути сохранения
        self.btn_browse_save_folder.clicked.connect(self.browsefiles2)  
        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.start)

        # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv #
        self.folder_path = None
        self.num_files = None
        self.column = None
        self.row = None
        self.save_path = None
        
    def browsefiles1(self):
        self.folder_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Выбрать папку", ".")
        if not self.folder_path:
            return
            
        self.path1.setText(self.folder_path)        
        self.num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(self.folder_path + '/1')
                         if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.folder_path + '/1', f))])
        self.count_label.setText(str(self.num_files))
        img_test = Image.open(self.folder_path + '/empty.tif')
        (self.column, self.row) = img_test.size
        self.size_label.setText(str(self.column) + 'px' + ' X ' + str(self.row) + 'px')

    def browsefiles2(self):
        self.save_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Выбрать папку", ".")
        self.path2.setText(self.save_path)
    
    def start(self):
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, self.num_files)
        
        self.thread = Thread(
            self.num_files, self.folder_path, self.save_path, 
            self.row, self.column
        )
        self.thread.stepSignal.connect(self.uilabels)
        self.thread.start()
        
    def uilabels(self, step, path):
        self.steps_status_label.setText(str(step+1)+' из '+str(self.num_files))
        self.progressBar.setValue(step+1)
        
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        label.setFixedSize(187, 106)
        label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(path).scaled(150, 106))

        column = 5        
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(label, step // column, step % column)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо, программа действительно работает так как нужно, теперь попробую самостоятельно разобраться и понять ваш код. Спасибо еще раз огромное очень помогли в освоении

Comment: @СветланаУстимова пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный и полезный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour